# Black screen once locked & cannot be turned on

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, intel-graphics, thinkpad

After updating Ubuntu to 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS, I have a problem when locking my laptop. It is a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Gen 10 Carbon with Intel Iris xe Graphics.

After clicking the lock button or "closing" the device the screen turns off but when clicked the button to exit from the "locking" mode the screen remains black.

The only way I can solve this issue is forcing my device to turn off and turn it on again.

What is a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 2):

Add to /etc/environment (in Ubuntu 22.04):

```
MUTTER_DEBUG_ENABLE_ATOMIC_KMS=0
```

or in Ubuntu 22.10 and later:

```
MUTTER_DEBUG_FORCE_KMS_MODE=simple
```

and then reboot.

Or just do Ctrl+Alt+F1.

This is my file:

[image]